# Using Fn keys in PhpStorm on Mac

Tags: macos, ide, phpstorm, shortcut

I want to be able to use PhpStorm short cuts involving the function keys `F1`, `F2`, `F3` etc...

The problem is that I'm on a Mac and the function keys are assigned to other functions such as brightness, volume, etc...

I know I can change this in my Mac System Preferences, but I'd rather keep those as they are when I'm not in PhpStorm.

I have tried to map (for example) brightness up to a shortcut that is assigned to `command-F2` by default. PhpStorm won't recognise the keystrokes or assign them.

Are there any other ways to achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

Use (Fn + F1), (Fn + F2)... short cuts for function keys or for other functions (such as brightness, volume) if you change it in System Preferences.

Comment: I'm trying to avoid having to use the Fn key. Since in combination with alt, alt-shift, alt-control etc, it requires hitting 3 or 4 keys at once. I'm looking for a way to configure php storm to accept alt-<brightness up> for example.

Comment: Perhaps this should be reworded as a PhpStorm specific question.